# I don't understand Unit Tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

So I'm trying to do some unit tests and I am completely lost.
This is my function:

```
showNotification = function(notificationBoxElement, validationErrorObject) {
    notificationBoxElement.show();
    notificationBoxElement.find('div div:last-of-type ul').empty();
    for(var inputLabel in validationErrorObject) {
        if(validationErrorObject.hasOwnProperty(inputLabel)) {
            notificationBoxElement.find('div div:last-of-type ul').append('<li><strong>' + inputLabel + ': </strong>' + validationErrorObject[inputLabel] + '<span></span></li>');
        }
    }
    notificationBoxElement.addClass('alert-danger');
};
```

Im am using Jasmine with Karma test runner. My question is what exactly should I test? Ideally I want my test to be the most robust possible, so I would like to test the DOM? The arguments? If I test the DOM, what do I test? Do I test if li are inserted in the ul and how many and if they got the right text in them? Do I test that the element is now visible because of the show function?

If I am testing the arguments, should I test for all the values possible? Or should I just test that notificationBoxElement is a dom element and that validationErrorObject an object? Why try to check the result with all possible values of arguments if I can only test if validationErrorObject is an object? Lots of things I don,t understand, please help me out!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about achitecture, which belongs to [programmers.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to test what the code does.

For testing DOM manipulation which your code is doing.  You have a couple of options.

1. Spy on the JQuery functions and make sure that they are called.  You would create a spy for `show()`, `empty()`, `append()`, etc.  And make sure that they are called and with the proper arguments.  The downside of this is that you are tied to jQuery and can make your tests complicated.
2. You can attach a elements to the DOM and make sure that the manipulations happen on those.  So in your test, you would add a `beforeEach` function that sets up elements of the DOM in the initial state that you want before the function is called.  Then in your test you make sure that the properties are modified correctly (i.e. the element is now visible, one is emptied, and correct children are added).  Then you can have a `afterEach` method that removes those elements from the test results page.

As for the arguments that you pass into your function, you want to be comprehensive.  So you want to pass in arguments that will cause changes to your functionality.

Based on what you are doing, I would use the second option, as it isn't tied to any specific code.  You are able to refactor your javascript without breaking your tests and ensuring that your code is still behaving correctly.  For example, you would pass an empty object and one with multiple error properties to make sure that you handle appending information.

Comment: Thank you! The DOM manipulation testing part is clear, but I' still confused on how I should test the arguments.

Comment: You have control of the arguments, you don't need to 'test' them.  You pass them in so you would pass in the DOM Element and an object into your function and make sure that things happen correctly.  When you are testing treat the function/class method as a black box.  For a given set of inputs, you check to make sure that a given output is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests should test small isolated issues. You should write a test for each piece you mention in your question. A lot of the time, you will end up with several tests to cover the same feature.

Coverage is a common metric used to measure how well tested your code is. I'm not familiar with Karma, but most test frameworks have a coverage command that will tell you what % of your code is covered with by the tests.

Overtime, you will start to develop a better sense of how to write tests efficiently.